# I try to open chrome or firefox on python with chromedriver or geckodriver but any page is opened

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I aim at building a programm to open a website (supreme) faster. Here is the programm :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\\...\\...\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32')
driver.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')
```

But when I launch it, nothing happens, python notices : [finished in 0.3s], and not any website is opened. Can someone tell me what is wrong ? Thanks a bunch

Comment: What do you mean any website is opened?

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: When I launch the programm, the website supremeneywork is supposed to be opened, isn't ? It's not my case @demouser123

Comment: When I launch the programm, the website supremeneywork is supposed to be opened, isn't ? It's not my case @Murthi

Comment: What website is opened. This works fine on my system.

Comment: No website is opened, there is no reaction. Strange @demouser123